# Python - deleting variables from text-data using regex

Tags: python, regex, list, variables

I am using python. I want to delete the line of a file which contains varaibles (input_numb ) the user can put in.

```
 input_numb = ['13', '04'] ## These are variable (depending on what the user puts in)
```

The variables are only supposed to be deleted if they a written with no other text in a line. If there is some text before or after it they are not to be deleted. I tried it with the regular expression below (line ) but it still returns all 13 and 04.

```
line = line.replace('\^'+input_numb+'\$', '')
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
13
Some text is good.
The text has 13 lines
13 is a nice number.

13
Some text.
Some more text 04.

04.
Some text.
```

The output data is which:

```
Some text is good.
The text has 13 lines
13 is a nice number.

Some text.
Some more text 04.

Some text.
```

Comment: `.replace` only supports plain string substitutions. Use `re.sub` to use a regex one. Something like `line = re.sub('(?m)^(?:{})$'.format("|".join([re.escape(x) for x in input_numb])), '', line)`.

Comment: Note that `04.` is not alone, there is a `.`. What are the real requirements? Please show the whole relevant code snippet (how are you reading in the data?). If you read a file line by line and write only valid lines, and if you allow any chars other than digits after the number, try https://ideone.com/bCM6F7.

Comment: the 04. was a typing error, sorry.

Comment: Ok, so, are you reading line by line? `rx = re.compile(r'^(?:{})$'.format("|".join(input_numb)))` with `if not rx.search(line)` should work then, see https://ideone.com/ranwjT

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest omitting all lines that fully match your `input_numb` list items.

Compile the following regex:

```
rx = re.compile(r'^(?:{})$'.format("|".join(input_numb)))
```

And then test each line for the pattern match, and if there is no match, write the line to the new file, else, do nothing:

```
if not rx.search(line):
    fw.write(line)  # where fw is the file handle where output is written
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/ranwjT).

In some cases, you might probably want to strip the line from the trailing whitespace, `if not rx.search(line.rstrip()):`.